# Combining partition files to create a .dmg file

Tags: macos, filesystems, partitioning, disk-partitioning

In order to use a USB device I bought, I need to install some drivers from a CD, but strangely, the files on the CD look like a disk image that was split into files for each partition.

[image: the files in question]

Does anyone have an idea of how to put these together so I can get the drivers?

Comment: "driver on CD" that's something that I haven't done … in a while! Is that driver for your version / platform of Mac OS? And yes, this looks like someone was not able to burn a CD properly, or Mac OS finder does something strange to CDs that aren't ISO9660-formatted but instead partitioned. Does the CD appear as one device in `diskutil list`? (Note: never used a mac in my life, this is just me searching stuff on apple.stackexchange.com)

Comment: My Mac doesn't have a CD drive—I put the CD in a Windows machine and copied the data to a USB stick (the files looked the same on Windows). The CD has folders for Linux, Windows, and Mac, and within the Mac folder are three folders for different versions of MacOS. It seems like they were trying to create a dmg file with the Mac drivers and put it on the CD, but they did it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to rename the hfs partition and add a .dmg file extension, as it turns out that .dmg files contain raw data anyways. I was able to mount it and install the drivers.